# How can I show that there is a unique n×n permutation matrix P such that Aˆ = PA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, permutations

I am trying to write a proof for following statement:

Let A be an n×n matrix and let Aˆ be a matrix that is obtained from A by scrambling the rows. Show that there is a unique n×n permutation matrix P such that Aˆ = PA

So, I was thinking to take a matrix (let say 3 by 3 ) and show explicitly that among three possible combinations of P only one satisfies the condition A^ = PA, i.e. just to show the calculations and say that all results are different and there is only one where  A^ = PA. Is there any other more general way to show the uniqueness of that permutation matrix P?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Look at 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&..1 \\
1&1&1&..1 \\
1&1&1&..1 \\
...&...&...&...\\
1&1&1&..1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

or even $A=0_n$.

Comment: Hi @N.S. could you explain little more detailed, because I don't really see what we can get out of this 1 and 0 matrices

Comment: @DanF. If $P$ is ANY permutation matrix, what is $PA$?

Comment: It is just a matrix with rows switched depending on the P

Comment: @DanF. And what do you get if you switch the rows of a matrix will ALL entries equal?

Comment: the same exact matrix. but that means that it won't depend on matrix P , therefore it is not unique, it can be any P matrix. However in my case I need to find a unique P

Comment: @DanF. So you are trying to prove that the matrix $P$ is unique... If you manage to prove it, your proof will hold for ALL choices of $A$. In particular the claim will also be true for THIS $A$.

Comment: Sure, but again the question is how do I manage to prove it? Just by using multiplication property?

Comment: @DanF. And again: If you manage to prove it, for this particular matrix you prove something which is not true... So let me ask it clearly: how can you prove something which is not true?

Comment: Oh ok , I see where you're taking me.. if I prove that for matrix with only 1's or only 0's the permutation won't change anything, that would mean that for any other matrix , where each row differs from others it will scramble the rows, thus the permutation suppose to be unique

Comment: @DanF. No. What I am saying is that the claim will be true for SOME matrices, but not for ALL. As stated, you are trying to prove this claim for all matrices, which is not true.